# Linux script to fill up my diskspace

Tags: linux

I need a script to fill up my diskspace on my Linux box. It would be best if I can leave 200 MB free. I have [Nagios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) installed, and it should email me when something like this happens, but how do I test it?

I have [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) and [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) installed so if you want to use that then sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ***Disclaimer:*** I'm not responsible if this screws your system in any way... just saying...

Something like this should work:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/tempFiller.deleteMe bs=1M count=$COUNT
```

`$COUNT` needs to be replaced with how big the file should grow in MiB.

Comment: I'm going to test on my VM box FIRST! (but not now. i am pleasantly surprised how fast this was answered)

Comment: You can make dd perform a lot faster by using a bigger block size. Try with dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/tempFiller.deleteMe bs=1M count=$COUNT, where $COUNT is size in megabytes.

Comment: `bs`, not `ibs`. `bs` sets both `ibs` (input block size) and `obs` (output block size).

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done by:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/tempFiller.deleteMe ibs=1M count=$sz
```

If any one can answer what if ibs=1M is replaced by bs=1M.